# Of a column, get the indices of first and last occurrences in certain context

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

df

| index | y position | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 3 |  |
| 3 | 2 |  |
| 4 | 1 |  |
| 5 | 0 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 |  |
| 7 | 3 |  |
| 8 | 2 | 1 |
| 9 | 5 |  |
| 10 | 0 | 5 |
| 11 | 0 | * |

`*` = Special value to be filled later

I'm calculating the total distance taken only when its y coordinate values drop. When it's decreasing subsequently, I only take the last index that has all the previous (continued) distance summed up (as shown in the column desired result).

If the distances are the same subsequently, then I would like to put in some unique value so that I can replace all of them later with one value.

There are millions of rows to go through so for loop will take too long. Is there be a faster way **without using a for loop**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `cumsum` to identify blocks of continuous strictly decreasing values:

```
# Δy
d = df['y position'].diff()

# Δy < 0
m = d.lt(0)

# identify blocks 
b = (~m).cumsum()

# group + transform
s = d.mask(~m).abs().groupby(b).transform('sum')

# select last values per group
df['result'] = np.select([~b.duplicated(keep='last') & m, d.eq(0)], [s, '*'], '')
```

**Details:**

Calculate [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) on `y position`:

```
print(d)

0     NaN
1     1.0
2     1.0
3    -1.0
4    -1.0
5    -1.0
6     2.0
7     1.0
8    -1.0
9     3.0
10   -5.0
11    0.0
Name: y position, dtype: float64
```

Identify continuous blocks of strictly decreasing values using [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
print(b)

0     1
1     2
2     3
3     3
4     3
5     3
6     4
7     5
8     5
9     6
10    6
11    7
Name: y position, dtype: int64
```

[`group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) the consecutive differences on continuous blocks (`b`) and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) using [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
print(s)

0     0.0
1     0.0
2     3.0
3     3.0
4     3.0
5     3.0
6     0.0
7     1.0
8     1.0
9     5.0
10    5.0
11    0.0
Name: y position, dtype: float64
```

Then use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with conditions and corresponding choices so as to keep only the last summed distance per block of continuous decreasing values:

```
print(df)

    y position   result
0            1        
1            2        
2            3        
3            2        
4            1        
5            0     3.0
6            2        
7            3        
8            2     1.0
9            5        
10           0     5.0
11           0       *
```